# PHP - Check if field CONTAINS vs is Equal To

Tags: php

I'm trying to check if one of my fields CONTAINS (rather than is equal to)  an item grabbed from my $user variable. My field (field_targetuser) contains a string of numbers: 45, 409, 47, 100.

I'm trying to see if field_targetuser contains the grabbed uid (47). How should I be writing the below in order to accomplish this? Apologies for my newbness.

```
global $user;

if($user->uid == $data->field_targetuser)          
{
    return false;
} else {
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Since it is a string you could use `strpos()` to find out if the specific number is in the string.

Comment: Don't use a string operation for this. If you check for `47`, you'll also match `147`. Split the string into an array with `explode()`, then use `in_array()`.

Comment: @JayBlanchard won't that be a problem with numbers like 'XX47' ?

Comment: Yes, of course it would be. I was making the assumption it was a well-known string.

Comment: @Barmar Ahh that makes sense. How should this look then? PHP is fairly new to me...

Comment: Is this list coming from a database column? You should probably normalize the schema. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad

Comment: Then you would be able to match the uid in the database query.

Comment: Also be careful as in your example `45, 409, 47, 100` there are spaces which if you use `explode()` will form part of the values in the array.  You may need to `trim()` the values before `in_array()` will find anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use explode() with `,` parameter, which will make an array of the ids.

```
$arrTargetUserIds = explode(',', $data->field_targetuser);
```

Then find inside the array.

```
if(in_array($user->uid, $arrTargetUserIds)){
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually PHP `explode()` to split your string as an array and `in_array()` to check the **uid** is within the exploded array. Also add `array_map()` to trim the white spaces around the numbers. Let's do it this way-

```
<?php
$user = new stdClass();
$data = new stdClass();
$user->uid = 47;
$data->field_targetuser = array_map('trim', explode(',', '45, 409, 47, 100')); 

if(in_array($user->uid,$data->field_targetuser))          
{
    print "Exists";
    return true;
} else {
    print "Not Exists";
    return false;
}
?>
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/NcbdW